# Troubleshoot "Failed to Create the Java Virtual Machine" when launching Import.io

Tags: java, import.io

For several months I've been getting this error when trying to launch the Import.io app on Windows 10:

[image: Error]

"Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

The company assures me that they don't have this problem, so it must be with my system.

I notice that this app installs its own copy of JRE in the program folder:

[image: jre]

If I try to launch the .exe from the command line I get the same pop-up error message.

I've installed and reinstalled Java a number of times. My Java version is definitely up to date. The same can be said of the Import.io app.

I've found other SO questions where this problem was encountered with Eclipse, but Eclipse works fine for me and their solutions seem to be app-specific. For that matter, NetBeans also works fine and I can use Java on the command line just fine.

Comment: This usually means there is a problem with the startup/command line options.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's a GUI app, to my knowledge no CLI, so what could I do to troubleshoot that? Should I launch the .exe from cmd with a certain option?

Comment: I get this kind of error every now and again when my system is short of memory. Also, you could be supplying an invalid flag to the JVM. How are you launching the JVM? Can you paste the JVM options here?

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich I see. I will do a test to see if it works with all RAM being free. As for the JVM -- I just launch the Import.io GUI app. I haven't been manually launching Java. JDK is on my environment PATH.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with `import.io` specifically. Normally for java-based Windows distros, there would be a configuration file with jvm settings somewhere next to the exe that launches the app. Example  for IntelliJ IDEA: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`. Your could also try launching the exe from cmd window and see if it prints anything. Also check if it writes any logs.

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich  I know what you mean. With this app, they try to keep it simplistic and don't have such configuration options (also, I can't open the app anyway).  I tried starting the .exe from the command line and the same pop up error message occurred. I noticed that it has its own JRE in the program folder, jre1.8.0_40. I updated the question with a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Hack-R If it is of interest, we will be releasing a web based product in the very near future. The product will both be more intuitive and wont rely on any of the things that are causing this issue.

Comment: @AlexBamford That's definitely of interest. For the record when you say "we" that's Import.io . By the way, I eventually DID get Import.io to work on a Windows 7 machine. The Java problem must be related to the newer versions of Windows. I remember that back in 2013-2014 the web app Import.io was amazing, but then the extractor, crawler, and connector functionality became only for the desktop app which I hadn't been able to get working until last night (and still only on win 7). I think it's worth figuring out the Java error so Win 10 works. Let me know if u have any thoughts.

Comment: @Hack-R Yes import.io is what I meant by "we", apologies! The Java error doesn't occur on all Windows 10 so it's hard to replicate. It's unlikely that it will get looked at anytime soon because the new release in part is designed to get around these kind of issues.